# How to pass a xml as a value for an attribute

Tags: xml

I need to pass a xml as a value for the attribute `att`

If I gave inside the quote it giving the parsing error. How to do this?

```
<r b="Y">
    <c att=" ">
</r>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to esacpe some of the characters in the value:

```
<r>
   <c att="&lt;root id='42' /&gt;" />
</r>
```

But if you use a proper XML library, it will take care of the escaping for you.

Never cut and paste XML!